# Change column type without ruining checkpoint

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake, delta

I'm working with two Delta sources, bronze and silver. Silver data is continuously streamed from bronze with checkpointing enabled. I need to update a column type in the bronze table, which requires using the `overwrite` mode along with the `overwriteSchema` option. However, I'm concerned about breaking the checkpointing mechanism. Is there a way to perform this update without disrupting the checkpointing process?